# Google 2-Step Verification (Android) Google prompt does not send to every phone where signed in

Tags: google-account, 2fa

For Google 2-Step Verification (Android) Google prompt, from Google UI, it states that 'After you enter your password, Google prompts are securely sent to every phone where you're signed in.' But, that is not true. I have 3 phones which are signed in. But Google prompt keeps popping up only on one phone. This annoys me much because I don't take that phone with me all the time. I don't want to sign out that phone because I need to use it sometimes too. How can I let Google prompt send to all the signed in phones? (OR temporarily block that one without signing out)

Comment: Can you check on https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification if the devices are listed on "Google prompts"? Also, you might be interested in the official help center for [Sign in with Google prompts](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7026266), particularly for "You don't get a Google prompt".

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks a lot for the information. They are listed on "Google prompts". I read the section about "You don't get a google prompt". But I don't find google play services app in the play store app. Thus, no way to update it. Maybe something wrong with the google play services app. Not really sure. Cheers.